# Auto suggest both words and phrases in solr?

Tags: solr, autosuggest

I have been able to implement either a word specific suggestion from solr or a phrase specific one for example

```
 <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
          generateWordParts="1" 
          generateNumberParts="1" 
          catenateWords="1" 
          catenateNumbers="1" 
          catenateAll="0" 
          splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
</analyzer>
```

The above code help's in getting single word suggestion like `he => help, hell, hello` etc.

```
 <analyzer>
       <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

The above code help's in getting whole phrase like `he =>  hell boy the movie, hell with you` etc.

How to integrate both so I get `he => hell, hello, hell boy the movie` etc.